# Why do we need MICE in order to build muon accelerators?

Tags: particle-physics, leptons

I heard that the [MICE](http://mice.iit.edu) team (International Muon Ionization Cooling Experiment) have made great progress towards the realization of a high-energy leptonic synchrotron.

Why is the MICE experiment an important step towards a muon synchrotron?

How would one create a beam of muons?

Comment: Hit a large amount of matter (lead/mercury) with a lot of high energy protons, resulting muons are collected/steered/filtered by magnets like any other charged particle

Comment: Their biggest problem is probably that they are a nuclear research lab with a project  called ISIS - let's hope a certain president doesn't get confused

Answer (score 1):

> [To demonstrate that the volume](http://mice.iit.edu/) occupied by a muon beam can be reduced (“cooled”) would be to establish the feasibility of muon accelerators for particle physics. Muon accelerators have the potential to unlock the secrets nature has hidden in the properties of the neutrino and to provide the capability to deliver collisions even more energetic than those that can be achieved at the LHC. MICE will deliver the necessary, seminal, demonstration of cooling.

To create an accelerated beam, one needs a beam to start with.i.e. a large number of particles moving in the same direction within a small volume/pulse. Creating muons by scattering nuclei is the simplest part, they have to be manipulated with magnetic fields so as to form a beam that can be accelerated.  The small pulse volume of a beam is necessary so that interactions can occur on a target, and very important in colliders, so as to have large probabilities of scattering.

The MICE experiment aims to prove the feasibility of this. Please note that muons are unstable, and everything has to be manipulated within their lifetimes, so it is not a trivial experiment.

> [A beam of primary particles](http://mice.iit.edu/about-mice/), for instance protons, can be created all heading in the same direction rather like a military marching band. Muons, by contrast, are created in processes that yield a “cloud” of particles. Capturing the muon cloud to produce a beam results in something which is may be likened to a mixed group of pedestrians crossing a bridge; they are all crossing the bridge, but they are moving from one side of the bridge to the other as they go, to see the sights. If present-day focussing techniques were to be used, a beam that is tens of centimetres in diameter would be produced. An accelerator that could accept such a wide beam would need to have extremely large magnets, which would be very expensive to build and to run. Furthermore, the resulting particle intensity would be insufficient to make many of the most exciting measurements in which we are interested.

Please note that muons are unstable, and everything has to be manipulated within their lifetimes, so it is not a trivial experiment.